# change "node" command into "nodejs" on windows

Tags: linux, node.js, windows

I am working on a nodejs project that I got from a linux user and he asked me to change the node command to nodejs , and I am using a windows system.

So instead of node index.js I need nodejs index.js

I have tried the doskey command but it does not seem to work

```
    doskey nodejs=node
```

as I get just an arrow on the next line when I type in nodejs index.js

Does anyone have another workaround or way to do this , if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file `nodesjs.bat`

```
@<path-to-node.exe>\node.exe %*
```

and put the batch file into the path.